# Would it be appropriate to replace a question with a related question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Assuming that you are the author of the original question and you feel as though you have made progress due to the answers given, but you are not satisfied or you have not reached the mathematical equation you aspired to achieve, would it be appropriate to replace the existing question with your new, highly-related one?  For example, you are stuck on a specific part of an algorithm.  Somebody makes a helpful post and you modify your algorithm.  You get most it worked out.  Your original question might have been something like "how do I do this algorithm?" and now your question is "how do I implement or fix part A of this algorithm?".  It's not exactly the same question, really, but it is part of the process of finding the correct answer to the original question.

So, **would it be acceptable to replace your question, A, with a highly-related question, B, which still deals with the same problem in some way or another?**

Comment: Not a good idea, for several reasons. You asked a question, and in good faith people answered it. So it is time to move on. Adding items to the question is probably poor strategy. It is likely that relatively few people will take note of the new items. Best, it seems to me, is a new question with appropriate back reference.

Comment: When you edit your question, it is returned to the top of the question list again, meaning it would receive more views again, as if it were new. However, I do agree with your reasoning (and I never said I vouched for replacing the question, I was just opening it to discussion for others to think about as well).

Comment: I know it returns to the top of active. I think not to newest. I do not know what proportion of users use active as default, and what proportion use newest.

Answer (score 8):

You say that you have helpful answers. If the new question invalidates any of those answers, I think it would not be respectful of the people who have helped you to change the question and invalidate their answers. Perhaps appending a new section to the question (labelled as such) or opening a new question would be better.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The dilemma is that if the question is replaced, answers could seem to be referring to something entirely different. The other issue is that if the question is asked again, but with some new progress, would it annoy users or not?  I would think that some users would find it exasperating.  **I even think it might be marked as a duplicate**, which is a very good reason not to post highly-related question B.  But then, if you don't want to make answers irrelevant by replacing the question and you don't want to get your related question closed for being a duplicate, what do you do?

Comment: If you are concerned about getting marked as a duplicate, and in fact, whenever a question builds on another one, **link to the old question** and explain in what aspects it is different. This will make the probability of closing as duplicate approximately zero.

Comment: That is good advice. I believe there is usually a reason why these questions are asked, and my reason was that I was stuck on an interpolation problem and I wasn't sure if I should have continued asking. I have solved the problem already, but it is a good method to know ;).